# IE CSS "filters" break alpha transparency

Tags: internet-explorer, css, transparency

I'm trying to figure out whether there's a weird solution to this weird problem.

Basically, IE >= 7 supports PNG transparency perfectly, and it has also supported a lot of the new cool stuff in CSS3 for years, through weird settings in the "filter" property.

However, when you apply a filter to an element that has a PNG background, the alpha-transparency of that background basically breaks (very similarly to how IE6 did).

If possible, I'd like to use the CSS3 properties that other browsers give me, and also get them in IE, instead of implementing them in JS (transitions) or not at all (rotations), but I can't unless I find a fix for the semi-transparency problem.

Has any of you found this problem and a fix for it?

---

EDIT: Added some code, although I'm not sure it exemplifies much:

```
#.faded {
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Fade(duration=2)
}
```

When I add this, PNG opacity breaks in IE for those element. It actually happens with all filters, or at least all I've tried.

---

Thank you!
Daniel

Comment: Can you please show us a code?

Comment: Just added it, although it doesn't really say much. This is not a problem with "my code", it's just something IE does when adding a filter, and i'm wondering whether there's some *other* filter I can add that'd magically fix it, or something like that.

Comment: What kind of PNG is giving you this problem?  PNG-8 or PNG-24?

Comment: PNG-24  ________________

Comment: Can you upload the image? Can we download it? Can you make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with that image so we can play with it? We love to play.

Comment: Actually, IE7 doesn't support it *perfectly*. It still has a number of clipping and drawing bugs which exhibit even in the absence of filters. It's almost like they slapped on a library made in 10 minutes to appease web designers for a while.

Comment: [Ugly as hell, but acceptable in my book, in IE8](http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/3mMgB/) (I don't have IE7, but it can't look better there...)

Comment: @Rudie, this shows the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/3mMgB/1/

Comment: Your goal isn't just transparency, but a fade effect? Using MS filters? Exciting stuff. Like BoltCock says: some stuff just doesn't work in IE. I recommend not caring: IE users don't get the full experience.

Comment: @BoltClock: Ok, I see your point. Maybe not perfectly, but worked "good enough", I never found problems with it, but I certainly didn't look in detail.

Comment: @Rudie: Yeah, exciting indeed. I also wanted rotation, which works using Matrices, but found the same transparency problem. I'm doing "graceful degradation", of course, and IE doesn't get either for now, but I'm not doing the "not caring" :-)  I found these filters and it seemed a cheap way to fake it and make IE also have these features. Didn't work.... Oh, well... But thought i'd ask. Thank you!

Comment: MS filters are often a 'very good' alternative. And there are MANY! So next time you're trying to fake a cool CSS(3) effect, check out the hundreds (!!) of filters (or Google). I **am** doing the not caring these days. IE is just so bad, I'm not even explaining myself anymore. IE users just don't deserve internet. And we are responsible to tell them.

Comment: @Rudie - That last line cracked me up but it's oh so true.

Comment: Well thanks Rob =) and be sure to spread the word.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/) or some other third party solution - no need to reinvent the wheel if an existing solution already works.

Comment: PIE goes crazy if you use it extensively on one page. Those htc files are crazy and vry inefficient.

Comment: PIE doesn't seem to support transitions (Which is what i'm trying to do with the fading), nor rotation (which filter does, through matrices, but also breaks transparency). If you know of any of these that do, I'd definitely try them. I know they work horribly, but may be better than not giving them the feature in the first place. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best try that I could active was: http://jsfiddle.net/xtT6b/

The point is to separate the block with filter from the block with background, and add the `alphaImageLoader` filter to the block with background.

However, it's not ideal and in IE7 on some images the result can be good, but on other there would be some artifacts.